# Spring Cacheable does not work

Tags: java, spring, caching

I'm using Spring with the config

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
            <set>
                <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean">
                    <property name="name" value="default"/>
                </bean>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="bucketsGenerator" class="net.rwchess.utils.PythonBucketsGenerationService">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="/home/bodia/server/jetty/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/python/"/>
    </bean>
..........

 <mvc:default-servlet-handler />    
</beans>
```

and there is method `generateBuckets()` in `PythonBucketsGenerationService` return value of which can be cached. So I declare:

```
@Service
public class PythonBucketsGenerationService {

    private String pythonDir;

    public PythonBucketsGenerationService(String pythonDir) {
        this.pythonDir = pythonDir;
    }

    @Cacheable(value = "buckets")
    public List<Bucket> generateBuckets(List<TournamentPlayer> players) {
    .....
    }
}
```

The problem is that the method is executed on each invocation even when the hashCode of `List<TournamentPlayer> players` has same value (I checked). `TournamentPlayer` has `equals()` and `hashCode()` correctly overridden. What is wrong here?

Comment: How do you invoke the `generateBuckets` method, from the same bean `this.generateBuckets(...)` or from an other bean `bucketsGenerator.generateBuckets(...)`?

Comment: I pass the reference of the bucket generator to another bean via constructor arg as `<constructor-arg ref="bucketsGenerator"></constructor-arg>` and then call generateBuckets inside this bean that reference bucketsGenerator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely missing enabling annotation-driven cache configuration (cache:annotation-driven). See this example:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <cache:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Go to this page for more documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Comment: I ended up using my own implementation of the cache as it was the only place I needed it and there was no need to create additional overhead, but thanks for the answer anyway.